# Suppress figure numbers only on certain slides in the latex beamer class?

Tags: beamer, floats

I am working on a presentation with the beamer-class. I have several slides with pictures on them, some pictures are logos where the logo is its own name. For example: Coca Cola has a logo that is its own name.

Therefore I want to suppress the caption under the picture, as it says the same thing that the logo says, which is pretty distracting on certain slides:

```
Coca Cola
Pic.1: Coca Cola logo

Pepsi
Pic.2: Pepsi logo
```

But when I omit the caption under one picture, the counter on the next picture falls one number short.

```
Coca Cola

Pepsi
Pic.1: Pepsi logo
```

To not confuse the audience I want the counter to be correct on all picture. Is there a way to do so?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[justification=centering,figurename=Abb.]{caption}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{grafik/studip.jpg}
    %\caption{Stud.IP-Logo}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    Next Slide
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{grafik/picture2.jpg}
    \caption{What a view}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a caption you can also manually add values to the figure counter

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[justification=centering,figurename=Abb.]{caption}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{pic}
    \addtocounter{figure}{1}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    Next Slide
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{pic}
    \caption{What a view}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah did not know ´addtocounter´, thank you! :)

Comment: @hamena314 You're welcome!

Comment: +1. Or shorter: `\stepcounter{figure}`.